# Find pair/triplets whose sum is least away from the given value

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

There are 2 variations of this question.

1. Given 2 arrays of integers, select single element from each array so that their sum is least away (numerically) from given integer value V. Sum can be greater than V.
2. Given 3 arrays of integers, select single element from each array so that their sum is least away (numerically) from given integer value V. Sum can be greater than V.

I know there is a naive O(n^2) and O(n^3) solution respectively for them and I'd like to ask if there's any approach which optimises running time.

Answer (score 0):

For the first case, you could sort both the arrays in `O(nlogn)`, and then for each element `x` in the first array, find `V-x` in the second array using the binary-search/upper-bound algorithm.
Its total complexity would still be `O(nlogn)` which is less than `O(n*n)`.

For the second case, you can apply a similar algorithm with `O(n*n*log(n))` complexity.

Comment: Thats why I said upper-bound algorithm. `ubx = upper_bound(arr, x)` returns the highest position where `x` can be inserted in a sorted array without breaking the order. So we can see if the `ubx - 1` has the exact value `V-x`. If not, then the `arr[ubx]` will have a greater value than `V-x` but with the smallest difference from `V-x`.